# How to stop the method .contains() whenever it finds the first match in a class?

Tags: java, contains

Suppose we are trying to find some string in a class, and suppose that class has this string repeated several times. How do I make the `.contains()` method stop whenever it finds the first match? Here is an example of what I mean:

```
      for (File f : list) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            walk(f.getAbsolutePath());
        }

        if (f.getName().endsWith(".java")) {

            System.out.println("File:" + f.getName());
            countFiles++;

            Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(f);

            while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {

                count++;

                String str = sc2.nextLine();

                if (str.contains("@Test")) {
                    System.out.println("this is a test class");

                }
```

As you can see I'm trying to find test classes so I'm looking for `@Test` notation, the program is working perfectly, but in this case its printing (this is a test class) several times as the class that I am testing has four `@Test` notations!

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe use `break`, see [Branching Statements: The break Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html) for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the break statement as well:

```
break;
```

The break statement will exit the inner most loop. The continue statement will skip the rest of the code in that loop and since your loop ends with the print statement the continue statement at the end of the loop will do nothing.

It looks like you have a for loop over each document and then a while loop for each line in the document and your code is returning each line in each document where it finds your string.

If you put a single break statement after the print statement it will print one line for each file where it finds your text.

If you would like it to stop after the first file, you'll need to create a flag like

```
boolean found = False;
```

and then put this inside the if statement below the print

```
found = True;
break;
```

Then at the end of while loop add this:

```
if(found){break;}
```

When your program finds the first instance of the string it will set the flag to true and exit the while loop, then since the flag is set to true, it will exit the for loop and finish after printing only the first instance.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `label`.

```
nextFile:  //add this label
for (File f : list) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        walk(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    if (f.getName().endsWith(".java")) {

        System.out.println("File:" + f.getName());
        countFiles++;

        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(f);

        while (sc2.hasNextLine()) {

            count++;

            String str = sc2.nextLine();

            if (str.contains("@Test")) {
                System.out.println("this is a test class");
                 continue nextFile;//go for next file
            }
```

**Edited**

Just in case you want to exit the method, I assume the return type is `void`;

```
if (str.contains("@Test")) {
     System.out.println("this is a test class");
     return; //quit method
}
```

Comment: In the context of his `for` loop, a label would be redundant.

Comment: @em1382, simply using `continue` keyword would only affect the enclosing `while` loop and not the topmost `for` loop. Hence the `label` is added.

Comment: Ah, missed that. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

`break` and `continue` are dangerous.  It's very easy to lose track of which block you're `break`ing or `continue`ing out of, especially when adding/editing functionality down the line.  This leads to subtle, painful bugs.

I would advise a different approach, one that's more OO: separate out a method that returns whether a `File` is a test file or not:

```
  for (File f : list) {
    if (f.isDirectory()) {
        walk(f.getAbsolutePath());
    }

    if (f.getName().endsWith(".java")) {

        System.out.println("File:" + f.getName());
        countFiles++;

        if ( isTestFile(f) ) {
            System.out.println("this is a test class");
        }
```

The implementation would contain your scanning code, and return on the first hit:

```
private boolean isTestFile(File file) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(f);

    while ( scanner.hasNextLine() ) {
        if ( scanner.nextLine().contains("@Test") ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This is also a clearer declaration of intent because it explains what you're trying to achieve in the method name.  It also gives the added benefit of separating the implementation from the intent - if down the line, you think of a better way of identifying a test class, you change the `isTestFile()` method body, and none of the rest of your code has to change.